# how to delete the output file through xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

From my input file, I am receiving previousevent and currentevent data.In my XSLT I am comparing both Previousevent and currentevent data - if it is not same I will produce the output file.

If it is same for previous event and current event , not required to generate the output...

In my XSLT I am checking the condition for previous and current if it will be  same empty file is generating. But I don't want to generate empty output file...

If any one knows please reply for this one.

Thanks:)

Comment: XSLT itself does not create any files; it's the calling application that does that. If it allows, you can do the transformation in memory and create a file only if the result is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *delete* the output file via (pure) XSLT, but in XSLT 1.0 you can create an empty file, or in XSLT 2.0 you can avoid creating the main output file by creating a different empty file instead...

### To create an empty output file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### To not create the main output file (requires XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:result-document href="empty.txt"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```